# Octave function definition error

Tags: function, octave

I am trying to use octave for the first time and I want to create a function as follows:

```
1;
 function test=calc(x)
         a=x^2;
         factorial(a)
 endfunction

 val = calc (3)
```

I saved this as calc.m and when I run it I get an error that variable x is not defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Update: The original question I managed to get working but now I ended up with another problem. Please consider the following code:

```
init = 5.;
function val=prodval(x)
  global init;
  val=x+init^2;
endfunction
fin=prodval(3)
```

When I save the script as test.m and run it i get the following error:

```
>> test

error: for x^A, A must be a square matrix.  Use .^ for elementwise power.
error: called from
    prodval at line 5 column 6
    test at line 7 column 4
```

What exactly is going on here? I do not see where I defined a matrix by mistake... I also realise that this may not be the best definition of a function but I am trying...

Comment: there are several things wrong with this code, but none of them relate to your error. I suspect you did not run this the way you say you did here. In general though, you are saving a file as a script, but then using the same name for a function inside it. This is just asking for trouble. You should generally prefer file-based function definitions than 'local / inline' ones, but if you do use a local one, make sure its name doesn't conflict with any other functions / variables / filenames present in your workspace, let alone the name of the very script you are using to define it in!

Comment: you were right! this was silly. I am too used to the way mathematica works and i just can't get my head around how octave script files should be structured. Could you point me towards some nice documentation for beginners please?

Comment: I find the [official manual](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/) to be surprisingly straightforward and friendly, and generally worth reading through. Otherwise, the best place to look for info would probably be the [octave wiki](https://wiki.octave.org) -- this includes links to tutorials on the front page etc. Also, since Octave explicitly aims to, and is mostly, matlab compatible, any decent matlab tutorial should apply to octave too.

Comment: do you mind helping me out with another quirk with octave. can you please look at the updated question? or should I ask another question? i feel this is another silly problem...

Comment: yes, you should, but in any case, you need to declare globals 'outside' as well. Since you didn't, inside the function the variable `init` is the global one, and since none was declared yet, it is initialised to `[]`. Type `[]^2` in your terminal and you'll see you get the same error. Also, if you want someone to get a notification, reply to them specifically, e.g. @TasosPapastylianou

Comment: or just @T would work as well (if there is no other person with name starting with T commented on the post) or `@Ta` or `@Tas` or `@Tasos` and so on. All of them work with the same rule

Comment: @Sardar really? huh. did _not_ know this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**

*For each scope you want a global to be "visible" you have to declare
it as global.* [Reference](http://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Global-Variables.html)

```
global init = 5;
function val = prodval (x)
   global init;
   val = x + init^2;  
endfunction

fin=prodval(3)
fin =  28
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the two opetions you wrote work (I tried them!) but what I was trying to do was write a function which needs some global variables like in the example I provided. My function is more complex than this example. Why do I get that error with my version? init is just a variable that takes a numerical value and not an array.

Comment: I have updated my answer according your needs. Please check

Comment: thank you! this worked! it will be a very long process for me to get my mind into octave's way of doing things! setting a variable as global in two places seems a bit redundant now... maybe I will understand why later.